# angularJS fill Select with Json data and select the selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have 2 entities. project and project_types.
One project has one or many project_types.

via ajax (ng-init) I get the project data (with related project_types of this project) 
and all the project_types (for selecting one or more project_types for a project):

```
$scope.showProject = function() {
        $http.post($scope.apiUrl+'/show', {
            projectslug: $attrs.projectslug
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.project = data;
        });

        $http.post($scope.apiProjectTypesUrl+'/index', {
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.project_types = data;
        });
    };
```

So in the {{project}} scope there is this json:

```
{"id":1,"slug":"test","active":1,"name":"Test","description":"dgdgdgdg","from":"2015-12-22 00:00:00","to":"2015-12-22 00:00:00","created_by":1,"updated_by":1,"created_at":"2015-12-22 12:08:47","updated_at":"2015-12-22 12:08:47","deleted_at":null,"from_date_time":"22.12.2015","to_date_time":"22.12.2015","formatted_description":"dgdgdgdg","users":[],"project_types":[{"id":4,"slug":"event","active":1,"name":"Event","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","updated_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","deleted_at":null,"pivot":{"project_id":1,"project_type_id":4,"created_at":"2015-12-22 13:13:12","updated_at":"2015-12-22 13:13:12"}}]}
```

and in the {{project_types}} scope there is this json:

```
[{"id":4,"slug":"event","active":1,"name":"Event","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","updated_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","deleted_at":null},{"id":5,"slug":"sfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsf","active":1,"name":"sfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsfsf","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 09:50:23","updated_at":"2015-12-22 09:50:23","deleted_at":null},{"id":6,"slug":"eteett","active":1,"name":"eteett","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 10:07:55","updated_at":"2015-12-22 10:07:55","deleted_at":null},{"id":7,"slug":"sfssfsf","active":1,"name":"sfssfsf","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 12:36:37","updated_at":"2015-12-22 12:36:37","deleted_at":null}]
```

In my html i create the select (multiple) field:

```
<select id="projectTypes"
   class="form-control"
   name="projectTypes[]"
   ng-model="project.project_types"
   ng-options="project_type.id as project_type.name for project_type in project_types"
   multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

So, in my select field there are 4 options (like in the project_types json - this is right)

But how can I select the right relations from my project in the select field?
The ng-model="project.project_types" contains this json:

```
[{"id":4,"slug":"event","active":1,"name":"Event","description":"","created_by":0,"updated_by":0,"created_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","updated_at":"2015-12-22 09:49:43","deleted_at":null,"pivot":{"project_id":1,"project_type_id":4,"created_at":"2015-12-22 13:13:12","updated_at":"2015-12-22 13:13:12"}}]
```

I cant get this to work... no value will be default selected in my select field...

thanks for push me into the right direction!

Comment: can you create a fiddle please? - jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the "track by"?

```
 ng-options="project_type.id as project_type.name for project_type in project_types track by project_type.id"
```

It would easier to help if you had a working code snippet or fiddle.

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions for the docs on "track by"